# async function for facebook api

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, async-await

I have a list of facebook post ids like `386050065267_10153256675935268`

by using below code i get a the required result as total count of like,share and comment

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    dynamic result = fb.Get(item.postId, new { fields = "shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)" });
}
```

is there any posibility of using async in that code?
I'm new to async feature please help me to do the right code,all thoughts are appreciated.!

Comment: You'd need to check the FB API to see if it provides any async APIs. There would not be much benefit in faking an async call using `Task.Run` for example.

Comment: There's a `GetAsync` method in the FacebookClient. You can await on that.

Comment: my confusion is doing async will improve the performance?

Comment: @marceln `GetAsync` returns void. There's `GetTaskAsync` though...

Comment: @TonyStark If that was your question then you should have included it *in your question*.

Comment: @I3arnon: Yes. Their documentation is a mess and they're obviously not .NET developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to the [documentation](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/reference/SDK/Facebook.FacebookClient.html) there is an `async` overload:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var result = await client.GetTaskAsync(item.postId, new {fields = "shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)"});
    // ...
}
```

This snippet of course must be inside an `async` method with an awaitable return value (i.e `Task` or `Task<T>`)